# Wallpaper clock

Tags: desktop-background, clock, wallch

where can i find Wallpaper clock saved as a .wcz file.

All the links I find point to "vladstudios" but are broken.

My goal is to be able to use the clock with wallch which then needs a .wcz file.

Or is there a description somewhere, how I create a clock / file myself

Comment: Why not use a clock with a 'normal' graphical interface (a window) like for example `oclock`, `xclock` or `xdaliclock`?

Comment: I am currently using the program conky manager, but would like this feature in wallch to work.